# How long does an Angular2 service hold the class variable values

Tags: angular, firebase, firebase-authentication, observable

I'm have an Angular2 app with a dataservice that should display different content based on the currently logged in user. **My issue is that my authentication service doesn't store the data value after it is first constructed making me unable to access the user id in my other data providers.**

Here's what I have currently done to accomplish this with 2 services, 1 component and 1 authguard (see below). The logic I would expect is:

1. *Authguard* is called before the inbox route is activated
2. *Authguard* calls the *AuthService* which subscribes to the FirebaseAuth and sets the *authState* variable
3. At all times if the user is logged in, the *DataService* should have a value for *authService.id* from the *AuthService*

However, what happens is that the authService.id yields *'Not set'* as it appears to never be set even though the user is logged in. This can be proved by adding `console.log(state)` after subscribing to auth$ in the *AuthService* which currently prints the currently logged in user.

My question therefore is how long is the variable *private authState* stored in the AuthService? Is there any other solution to obtaining the observable value of the *authService.id* variable before making other calls in my DataService? One solution I can think of would be using switchmap in the DataService for each data call but this seems suboptimal.

**AuthService**

```
@Injectable()
export class AuthService {

  private authState: FirebaseAuthState = null;

  constructor(private af: AngularFire, public auth$: FirebaseAuth) {
    auth$.subscribe((state: FirebaseAuthState) => {
      this.authState = state;
    });
  }

  get authenticated() {
    return this.authState !== null;
  }

  get id(): string {
    return this.authenticated ? this.authState.uid : 'Not set';
  }
}
```

**AuthGuard**

```
@Injectable()
export class AuthGuard implements CanActivate {
  constructor(private authService: AuthService, private router: Router) {}

  canActivate(): Observable<boolean> {
    return this.authService.auth$
      .take(1)
      .map(authState => !!authState)
      .do(authenticated => {
        if (!authenticated) {
          this.router.navigate(['/compose']);
        }
      });
  }

}
```

**Data Service**

```
@Injectable()
export class EmailService {

  private emails: FirebaseListObservable<IEmail[]>;
  private emailUserPath: string;

  constructor(private af: AngularFire, authService: AuthService) {
    this.emailUserPath = `/emails/${authService.id}`;
  }

  getAllEmails(): FirebaseListObservable<IEmail[]> {
    return this.af.database.list(this.emailUserPath);
  }
}
```

**Route module**

```
const routes: Routes = [
  { path: 'inbox',  component: InboxComponent, canActivate: [AuthGuard] }
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [ RouterModule.forChild(routes) ],
  providers: [AuthGuard],
  exports: [ RouterModule ]
})

export class EmailRoutingModule {}
```

**App Module**

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { HttpModule } from '@angular/http';

import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { EmailsModule } from './emails/emails.module';

import { AppRoutingModule }     from './app-routing.module';
import { AngularFireModule, AuthProviders, AuthMethods } from 'angularfire2';
import { UserSearchComponent } from './shared/user-search/user-search.component';
import {AuthService} from "./auth/auth.service";
import {AuthGuard} from "./auth/auth-guard";
import {EmailRoutingModule} from "./emails/email-routing.module";
import { UserOrLoginComponent } from './navigation/user-or-login/user-or-login.component';
import { NavigationListComponent } from './navigation/navigation-list/navigation-list.component';

export const firebaseConfig = {
  apiKey: "hidden",
  authDomain: "hidden",
  databaseURL: "hidden",
  storageBucket: "hidden"
};

const myFirebaseAuthConfig = {
  provider: AuthProviders.Google,
  method: AuthMethods.Popup
};

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    UserSearchComponent,
    UserOrLoginComponent,
    NavigationListComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    FormsModule,
    HttpModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    EmailRoutingModule,
    AngularFireModule.initializeApp(firebaseConfig, myFirebaseAuthConfig),
    EmailsModule // I include the Emails module below here
  ],
  providers: [
    AuthService,
    AuthGuard
  ],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

**Email App Module**

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { ComposeComponent } from './compose/compose.component';
import { EmailDetailComponent } from './email-detail/email-detail.component';
import { InboxComponent } from './inbox/inbox.component';
import { ReplyComponent } from './reply/reply.component';
import { ReplyListComponent } from './reply/reply-list/reply-list.component';
import { EmailService } from './shared/email.service';

import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import {ReplyService} from "./reply/reply.service";

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    FormsModule
  ],
  declarations: [
    ComposeComponent,
    EmailDetailComponent,
    InboxComponent,
    ReplyComponent,
    ReplyListComponent
  ],
  providers: [
    EmailService,
    ReplyService
  ]
})

export class EmailsModule { }

export { EmailService };
```

Comment: Do you provide `AuthService` in `AppModule` to make it globally singleton?

Comment: I provide it in a separate auth module that I then import in the app module

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They store their values as long as they live. When you navigate to somewhere outside of module that sets value on the service, you lose the value. Because you no longer have access to instance that has value set.

Services are singleton per provider. That means if you need a service/value globally, you need to make it singleton at global level. Providing `AuthService` at `AppModule` should solve your problem.

```
import { AuthService } from 'path/to/service'

@NgModule({
  imports: [ ],
  providers: [AuthService], //<-- provided globally
  exports: [ ]
})

export class AppModule {}
```

Comment: Thanks for that. However, I already set the AuthService as a provider in the NgModule:

`
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    UserSearchComponent,
    UserOrLoginComponent,
    NavigationListComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    FormsModule,
    HttpModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    EmailRoutingModule,
    AngularFireModule.initializeApp(firebaseConfig, myFirebaseAuthConfig),
    EmailsModule
  ],
  providers: [
    AuthService,
    AuthGuard
  ],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }`

Comment: Please edit your question and add module code.  This is not readable in the comments. Do you provide the service anywhere else too?

Comment: Good point Stefa. I edited the answer and included the App module and Email module above. Let me know if you can find anything that looks off